# Tutorial to connect Mantis bug tracker tool through MantisConnect

Tags: java, web-services, automation, bug-tracking, mantis

I want to connect the Mantis Bug Tracker tool through my Java code. I searched a lot and found i can do it using [MantisConnect](http://www.futureware.biz/mantisconnect/).  I tried to found some good beginner's article to accomplish my task using MantisConnect. But i couldn't. Please suggest me if any other good tutorial is available in internet. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: if possible we you share the sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MantisConnect is not needed, and I'd venture to say that it's out of date. What I suggest you do is pick up the prebuilt Axis 1 stubs, as documented in the [MantisBT integration documentation](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/developers.html#INTEGRATORS.JAVA)

Comment: Thanks Robert. I did my task.

Comment: Hi Robert, May i know how to log an issue with an attachment. I tried by using "mc_issue_attachment_add". It adds an issue with the file in a corrupted format. I tried many ways but couldn't. Used piece of code "portType.mc_issue_attachment_add(Username,Password, issueId,"Error.jpg", "base64", encodedAttachment);" Please let me know if any work around is there.